# Llenar un textarea con diferentes textos de inputs de un formulario

Tags: javascript, html

lo que necesito es insertar en un Textarea los datos de un formulario que se esta llenando

Ejemplo de formulario seria con Nombre, Apellido, Email, Telefono.

y en el Textarea insertar el valor de los inputs delante del texto ya predefinido, así:

Me llamo $Nombre $Apellido

y me puedes escribir al correo $Email

o llámame al $Telefono, espero tu llamada!

Todo tipo onchange mientras escriba el formulario aparezca en el textarea
todo esto con un botón de copiar al porta papeles debajo del textarea

espero me ayuden, de antemano Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te resumo como podrias hacerlo usando jquery

Form

```
<label>Nombre</label>
<input type="text" id="nombre" onkeyup="actualizar_textbox()" /><br>
<label>Apellido</label>
<input type="text" id="apellido" onkeyup="actualizar_textbox()" /><br>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" onkeyup="actualizar_textbox()" /><br>
<label>Telefono</label>
<input type="tel" id="telefono" onkeyup="actualizar_textbox()" /><br>
<label>Resultado</label>
<textbox id="textbox">No hay texto aun</textbox><br>
<input type="button" onclick="copiar('textbox')" value="Copiar datos" />
```

y su script

```
<script>
    function actualizar_textbox(){
        var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
        var apellido = $("#apellido").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
        var html = 'Me llamo '+nombre+' '+apellido+'<br> y me puedes escribir al correo '+email+'<br> o llamame al '+telefono+' espero tu llamada!';

        $("#textbox").html(html);
    }


        function copiar(element){
            var doc = document,text = doc.getElementById(element),range,selection;
            if(doc.body.createTextRange){ //ms
                range = doc.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(text);
                range.select();
            }else if(window.getSelection){ //all others
                selection = window.getSelection();
                range = doc.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(text);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            }

            let copySelected = document.execCommand('copy');
            if(copySelected){
                copySelected
                alert('Se copió la información');
            }else{
                alert('No se pudo copiar la información el navegador actual no soporta esta funcionalidad');                
            }
        }

</script>
```

Podes testearlo aca
https://jsfiddle.net/ja53vngd/2/

Comment: Hola @Pushuno, exactamente lo que necesito, solo un pequeño detalle, me gustaría con el salto de linea, que quedaran 3 lineas como en el ejemplo, se podrá? Saludos.

Comment: ahi actualice el codigo y agregue unos saltos de linea <br>